# 2 rotations with transform.Rotate() and transform.localEulerAngles() doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm trying to make a simple car simulator, and when I use the transform.Rotate() to rotate the wheels foreword (x axis), and the transform.localEulerAngles() to rotate in the turning direction (y axis), only the localEulerAngles() works. when I use only one method, the wheel foreword rotation (x axis) works, but I can't manage to make them both work. Do you have any ideas how to make them work together?

```cs
float ro = 20f; // 20 degrees turn
//to preserve the x and z values of rotation
Vector3 rot = wheel.gameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
//rotates the wheels angle
wheel.gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(rot.x, ro, rot.z);

float vel = wheel.rpm * 2 * Mathf.PI / 60 * Time.deltaTime * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
//rotates the wheels forward
wheel.gameObject.transform.Rotate(vel, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using localEulerAngles when you are having two different rotations, because when you have 2 movements if you use localEulerAngles you change the local angles with the movements you are providing themselves so you loose the reference of where the angular position of your axis is at.
You can indicate to the rotate method to rotate respect to the world, transform.rotate rotates the transform of your object relative to the world so you can handle simultaneus rotations together because world axis do not change.
Find below the code snippet that I tried, and the picture of my axis orientation which is not exactly the same as yours.

```
public class WheelTurning : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
float rpm=10f;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        turn(direction.left);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        turn(direction.right);
    }
    float vel = this.rpm * 2 * Mathf.PI / 60 * Time.deltaTime * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    rotate(vel);
}
enum direction
{
    left,
    right
}
void turn(direction dir)
{
    Vector3 rot = this.gameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    //rotates the wheels angle
    float rotation = dir == direction.left ? 20f : -20f;
    gameObject.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, rotation, 0), Space.World);
}
void rotate (float speed)
{

    gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, speed, 0);
}
```

}

[image: axis reference image]

However it is much more operative to use quaternions, try to check that out.
Hope that helps!

Comment: Tried this one but the problem is that I need absolute values for the turning direction (to set the rotation to 20 and not adding 20 to it), and therefore it starts spinning. But they both work

Comment: I do not get your point. If you want to turn a wheel it will alwiys be respect to its previous rotational postion. With that reference you can choose the value you like in the rotation vector Vector3(0, rotation, 0). If you want an absolute reference you can make a parent object and rotate this. Objects have the same world axis and when rotated or transformed, the children "suffer" the same transformation. You have to meke sure that the posistion in the childre is 0,0,0 as this is the distance respect to the parent position that will be the rotation pivot.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get your point. If you want to turn a wheel it will alwiys be respect to its previous rotational postion. With that reference you can choose the value you like in the rotation vector Vector3(0, rotation, 0). If you want an absolute reference you can make a parent object and rotate this. Objects have the same world axis and when rotated or transformed, the children "suffer" the same transformation. You have to meke sure that the posistion in the childre is 0,0,0 as this is the distance respect to the parent position that will be the rotation pivot.

```
 void setRotation()
{
    Vector3 rot = this.gameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    GameObject wheelParent = gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject;
    Vector3 rotationVector = new Vector3(0, 30, 0);//absolute turn set
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationVector);
    wheelParent.transform.localRotation = rotation;
}
```

Hope that helps.